# Populate a column by selecting a sub string from a string in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a column in oracle table with Values as below:

```
Column_name
test.123.yen.12345567
abc.234.rau.42525252
eng.111.rai.73540740
```

Now I have another column in the same table say regex_column. In this column I want to populate values in such a way that I want to extract the sub string from the string until the last occurrence.

The final result of the column should be like below.

```
regex_column
test.123.yen 
abc.234.rau
eng.111.rai
```

How can we achieve that using regex or is there any other way we can achieve this?

Comment: So you want to remove the last period and everything following it. What should be the result if there is NO period in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use Oracle's base string functions:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, '.', -1, 1) - 1) AS regex_column
FROM yourTable
```

You could also use a regular expression substring.

To address the edge case pointed out by @mathguy, if there were an entry having no period at all, then the call to `INSTR()` would return 0, and the `SUBSTR()` would just return the *last* character in the column.

Answer (score 0):

One way using regular expression function `regexp_replace` is:

```
select 
  regexp_replace(c,'(\.[^.]*$)')
from t;
```